# How do I fire an event in VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, events, raiseevent

I have a form that has a start button (to allow users to run the processes over and over if they wish), and I want to send a `btnStart.Click` event when the form loads, so that the processes start automatically.

I have the following function for the `btnStart.Click` event, but how do I actually tell Visual Basic 'Pretend someone has clicked the button and fire this event'?

I've tried going very simple, which essentially works. However, Visual Studio gives me a warning `Variable 'sender' is used before it has been assigned a value`, so I'm guessing this is not really the way to do it:

```
Dim sender As Object
btnStart_Click(sender, New EventArgs())
```

I have also tried using `RaiseEvent btnStart.Click`, but that gives the following error:

> 'btnStart' is not an event of 'MyProject.MyFormClass

#### Code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class frmProgress

    Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        ' Set up the BackgroundWorker
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

        ' Fire the 'btnStart.click' event when the form loads
        Dim sender As Object
        btnStart_Click(sender, New EventArgs())

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then

            ' Enable the 'More >>' button on the form, as there will now be details for users to view
            Me.btnMore.Enabled = True

            ' Update the form control settings so that they correctly formatted when the processing starts
            set_form_on_start()

            bw.RunWorkerAsync()

        End If

    End Sub

    ' Other functions exist here

End Class
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should send a button as `sender` into the event handler:

```
btnStart_Click(btnStart, New EventArgs())
```

Answer (score 11):

Steps in involved in raising an event is as follows,

```
Public Event ForceManualStep As EventHandler
RaiseEvent ForceManualStep(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
AddHandler ForceManualStep, AddressOf ManualStepCompletion

Private Sub ManualStepCompletion(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)        


End Sub
```

So in your case, it should be as below,

```
btnStart_Click(btnStart, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 7):

Just Call

```
btnStart.PerformClick()
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to implement a *bad* idea. Actually, you have to make a *subroutine* to accomplish these kind of tasks.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

      call SeparateSubroutine()

End Sub

private sub SeparateSubroutine()

   'Your code here.

End Sub
```

And then whereever you want to call the `btnStart's click event`, just call that `SeparateSubroutine`. This should be a correct way in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the button and make its `OnClick` Method public [as I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68708066/6702598).